# Why wasn't Tony Stark more affected by this?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In Avengers: Endgame, when Tony Stark steals the Infinity Stones from Thanos and inserts them into his own ad-hoc gauntlet, there isn't much of an energy outburst and Stark seems to be able to wield the gauntlet fairly easily:

By contrast, there is much more energy when Thanos gets all the stones:

The Hulk seems barely able to survive wielding them:

I understand that the actual snap killed Tony, but it seems he wielded the stones too easily. Is his nano-suit particularly good at buffering the power from the stones? Why didn't the gauntlet he designed previously for the Hulk do this?

Comment: @Jenayah thanks, I didn't see that question. I'm not sure if it should count as a duplicate. The question and especially the accepted answer are much more focused on the act of snapping than just wielding the stones.

Comment: Ah crap, I was sure there was an answer mentioning the fact that Hulk was in pain like crazy 'cause he was trying to bring Nat back (which is impossible and thus hurts him). That'd be (I think) the answer to your question but should also be covered by the dupe... I dunno. I personnaly do think it's a dupe, but will let other reviewers decide :)

Comment: I'm inclined to think this probably is a dupe but I don't want to VTC because I have a *Mjolnir-badge* in [tag:plot-explanation] and I don't think it appropriate to single handedly close the question when there is *some* doubt about it's dupeness in my mind.

Comment: BTW...the new Gauntlet wasn't designed for the Hulk...it was designed to fit anyone..they even argue about who would wear it.